# How to reduce this problem to linear programming one?

Tags: linear-programming

$C$ is a given binary matrix of $M \times N$, $l$ and $b$ both are vectors of size $N$ and $M$ correspondingly, with non-negative elements.

For given $k$ we need to find any matrix $A$ of $M \times N$ such that

$$
\max_{A_{i,j}} [(A \odot C) l]_k,
$$

s.t.
$$
A_{i,j} > 0, \sum_{j} A_{i,j} = 1,\,  
$$

$$
(A \odot C) l - b \geq 0,
$$
where last inequality considered element-wise and $\odot$ is element-wise product.

If we can solve the optimization problem without finding matrix $A$ or have a good lower bound for it, it will be great, too.

Comment: Shouldn't $b$ have dimension $M$?

Comment: What does subscript $k$ denote? Does it index $l$, in which case $0 \le k < N$? I don't see how it could, because $l$ after the dot product produces a scalar.

Comment: @Reinderien k denotes index -- matrix product with vector gives vector and we are interesting in maximizing k-th element of it.

Comment: Keep in mind that LP doesn't maximize a multi-element objective. It only ever maximizes a scalar that's basically always a dot product. If every element has the same weight, you need to re-express your objective with a sum over $k$.

Comment: @Reinderien I need only one selected k, so my objective is dot product of vectors l and vector of zeros with only 1 in k-th place

Comment: Is $k$ fixed, or is it an optimization parameter?

Comment: @Reinderien k is fixed along with C, l, b. Optimization parameters are only A_{i,j}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best guess:

With

- Index $0 \le i < M$
- Index $0 \le j < N$
- Known $C_{ij} \in \lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace \; \forall i,j $
- Known $b_i \ge 0 \; \forall i $
- Known $l_j \ge 0 \; \forall j $
- Known $0 \le k < N $
- Unknown $A_{ij} \ge 0 \; \forall i,j$

Minimize

$$\min_{A_{ij}} \left( -\sum_i \sum_j A_{ij} C_{ij} l_j \right)$$

but $i$ is fixed at $k$ and all other $i$ are ignored, so

$$\min_{A_{kj}} \left( - \sum_j l_j A_{kj} C_{kj} \right)$$

In practical terms, you simply drop all rows of $A$ and $C$ except those at $i=k$; and would also want to drop all $j$ for which $C$ is zero during your implementation; so

$$\min_{A_{kj}} \left( - \sum_{j| C_{kj}=1} l_j A_{kj} \right) $$

LP solvers will accept

$$c_j = -l_j \; \forall j| C_{kj}=1 $$

as the optimization coefficient vector.

Importantly, $A$ only has one subset of one row with any meaningfully optimized values. Your constraints will be similarly reduced. You need to decide what to fill $A$ with in the off-elements - zero? After optimization there's still an infinite number of states for the full version of $A$ that would satisfy your constraints. To demonstrate one simple option,

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

rand = default_rng(seed=0)

M = 9
N = 5
k = 1
b = rand.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=M)
l = rand.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=N)
C = rand.integers(low=0, high=1, endpoint=True, size=(M, N))
b *= C.any(axis=1)  # enforce feasibility for zero rows
i = k
j, = C[i, :].nonzero()

Arow_eq_1 = LinearConstraint(A=np.ones(len(j)), lb=1, ub=1)
ACl_ge_b = LinearConstraint(A=l[j], lb=b[i])

result = milp(
    c=-l[j],              # maximize ACl
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0),  # Ai,j >= 0
    constraints=(Arow_eq_1, ACl_ge_b),
)
assert result.success, result.message

is_nonzero = C.any(axis=1)
A = np.zeros((M, N))
Cl = C[is_nonzero, :] * l
A[is_nonzero, :] = Cl / Cl.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
A[~is_nonzero, 0] = 1
A[i, j] = result.x

print('A =')
print(A)
print('Evaluated constraint 1: 1 =', A.sum(axis=1))
print('Evaluated constraint 2: 0 <=', (A*C)@l - b)
```

```
A =
[[0.53321056 0.46522785 0.00156159 0.         0.        ]
 [1.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [1.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.00306413 0.95935669 0.03757918]
 [0.         0.99665462 0.00334538 0.         0.        ]
 [0.5231906  0.4564854  0.00153224 0.         0.01879176]
 [0.35357075 0.30849157 0.00103549 0.32420278 0.01269942]
 [0.         0.47798969 0.         0.5023333  0.01967701]
 [0.53404452 0.46595548 0.         0.         0.        ]]
Evaluated constraint 1: 1 = [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
Evaluated constraint 2: 0 <= [8.14456396 9.08093752 0.         8.22174277 7.31806353 7.71006106
 8.00036824 7.48383514 8.25159239]
```

Comment: You have the $k$ in the wrong place.  Also, you have ignored the $\ge b_i$ constraints, but for $i \not=k$, I guess you can take $A_{ij}=1$ for the $j$ with the largest $C_{ij}\ell_j$ and $A_{ij}=0$ for all the other $j$.

Comment: @RobPratt sigh, transposition errors. Does this look better? Re. constraints, I deliberately left that out because OP needs to decide how to populate non-optimized entries of $A$.

Comment: Yes, better now.

Comment: Thank you very much, especiialy for example code!

Answer (score 4):

If you change the lower bound $>0$ to $\ge 0$ (alternatively, $\ge \epsilon$ for some fixed positive $\epsilon$), this is already a linear programming problem.  Explicitly, the problem is to maximize $$\sum_j A_{kj} C_{kj} \ell_j$$ subject to
\begin{align}
A_{ij} &\ge 0 &&\text{for all $i$ and $j$} \\
\sum_j A_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
\sum_j A_{ij} C_{ij} \ell_j &\ge b_i &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

---

Assuming the problem is feasible, the optimal objective value should be
$$\max_j C_{kj} \ell_j,$$
attained by taking $A_{kj}=1$ for the largest $C_{kj} \ell_j$ among all $j$.